# how training keras model on tpu of local rtx gpu

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tpu, rtx

I use keras backend tensorflow.

I have RTX gpu on my local pc, and i want to training keras model on tpu(tensor core)

is there any method for this?

Comment: Tensor cores are not TPUs, at least not the same TPU concept by Google, its just an additional resource for the GPU to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tensorcore of RTX GPU and tpu og google's are different.